# Retrieve status of model training after closing notebook

Tags: python, keras, jupyter-notebook

I am training a deep learning model with Keras from a Jupyter notebook. Is there a way to retrieve the status bar showing how many epochs have been completed if I close the notebook?

Comment: No, as far as I know. I would recommend running your long-live experiments in your terminal, inside a tmux session, that way you will never lose track :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that information is not saved anywhere by default, it could only work if you save this information manually, or if you use something like the CSVLogger callback during training, as covered in the keras [docs](https://keras.io/callbacks/#csvlogger).